# Is it possible to use an init.gradle script in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm using the Gradle wrapper in a project in Idead. I have an `init.gradle` file in a non-standard location and need to find a way to specify it in Idea. I thought this could be done via the Gradle VM options setting field and entered `--init-script /path/to/init.gradle` in it, but this throws an `Unrecognized option --init-gradle /path/to/init.gradle` error when trying to re-import the project.

Is there some other way to do this that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set Gradle commandline options/arguments from the "Run" configuration panel:

[image]

If you set this option on the "Templates>Gradle" panel it will apply to all Gradle tasks invocation ( note that you need to execute tasks with Right-click/Run from the Gradle tool window:  double-click will not take the option into account..)

EDIT : another way is to add the commandline options directly in the "Run gradle task" window:

[image]

Comment: I'm more interested in the configuration on the right-hand side panel. I thought it would be possible to configure it from there? I mean -- the init script contains repositories and so on, which are required in order to be able to successfully re-import.

Comment: no sure to understand what you mean by "the right-hand side panel", but I have edited answer to add another solution to set these option.

Comment: Thanks for this example as well! Yeah, this is the panel that I'm talking about. If you click on the tool icon, it'll pop up the Gradle configuration dialog. In there, you can select things like whether to use an installation of Gradle, the built-in Gradle wrapper, or the project's wrapper. We're using the project's wrapper script and I was expecting it would be possible to set the init script through there, so that when you do a re-import, it wouldn't complain about artifacts which it "can't find", due to the repositories which aren't set otherwise. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok I understand. Unfortunately ,I fear it's not possible to set Gradle commandline options using the field "Gradle VM option" from this configuration window.. already tried several time, to set "--stacktrace" or "--warning-mode" options, I never could make it work... that's why I use the other solutions above (as workaround)

Comment: just found an old post on Jetbrains support, related to this question. the proposed answer is to use "Run" configuration (my 1st solution), it looks like no other way have been implemented since.  (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206840495-Passing-stacktrace-and-debug-options-to-gradle )

Comment: I was looking for another answer, but it seems like it's a limitation in IntelliJ. Thanks for your help!